# PySpark in K8S - I want to use JAR file that is in S3 location. I want to add JAR file in PySpark Jar location. How can I do the same?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

We have deployed Spark Operator in K8S. Now we are running different Spark Jobs. One of those Jobs have some specific JAR file requirement. We don't want to customize PySpark Image to include that JAR in PySpark Jar folder. Is it possible to specify the JAR file path (on S3) when submitting PySpark Job?

I have tried -

1. Specify the Packages under `spark.jars.packages`.
2. Specify the s3a://jar path under `spark.jars` package. But it doesn't work.